# Importing classes in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a little module that creates a window (program1). I'd like to import this into another python program of mine (program2).

How would I make it so I can make so program1 makes a window when referred to by program2?

The module I'd like to import(program1).

```
import Tkinter

class Class(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.Main()

    def Main(self):
        self.button= Tkinter.Button(self,text='hello')
        self.button.pack()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Class(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

How do I make program 2 do the function call self.Main() that's in program1?

Also how do I go about transferring values across programs?

Say in program1 x = 'hello', how do I get the value of x in program2?

Comment: your edited questions should probably be separate questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run the mainloop from program2, then:

```
import program1
app = program1.Class(None)
app.mainloop()
```

or, for less duplication:

```
# program1.py
...
def main():
  app = class(None)
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

and then

```
# program2.py
import program1
program1.main()
```